# Calculating slope of numpy array using gdal.DEMProcessing

Tags: python, gdal, dem

I am trying to compute the slope of a numpy array using `gdal.DEMProcessing`. Here is an example of what I am trying. Here in the example I am loading a portion of a DEM file, when I try to compute the slope I get out an array of -9999.

```
dem_ds = gdal.Open(str(dem_filename))
dem_arr = dem_ds.ReadAsArray(xoff=3584, yoff=0, xsize=512, ysize=512)

dst_filename = '/vsimem/slope.tif'

tmp_ds = gdal_array.OpenArray(dem_arr)
_ = gdal.DEMProcessing(dst_filename, tmp_ds, 'slope')
slope = gdal.Open(dst_filename).ReadAsArray()
slope.mean()
```

> -9999.0

It works by passing `dem_ds` instead of `tmp_ds` however the point would be to compute the slope of a general numpy array (without georeference) and not the full dataset as loaded from file.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`numpy.gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

```
import numpy as np

# Example 2D array of elevation, and constant gridsize
elev = np.array(
    [[2., 3., 2.],
     [3., 4., 4.]])
cellsize = 10.

# Evaluate gradient in two dimensions
px, py = np.gradient(elev, cellsize)
slope = np.sqrt(px ** 2 + py ** 2)

# If needed in percent, just multiply by 100
print(slope * 100.0)
# [[14.14213562 10.         22.36067977]
#  [14.14213562 11.18033989 20.        ]]

# If needed in degrees, convert using some trig functions
slope_deg = np.degrees(np.arctan(slope))
print(slope_deg)
# [[ 8.04946698  5.71059314 12.60438265]
#  [ 8.04946698  6.37937021 11.30993247]]
```

Comment: thanks Mike, that's indeed a way to work around it. The problem is that I would like to compute the aspect as well and that's why I wanted to use gdal. And would also like to figure out what is the issue with my attempt.